# ArrayOutOfBoundsException in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indexoutofboundsexception

I have following code in Java.

```
public class TestArray
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {

        int arr[]={23,12,1,4,1,4,23,6};
        int temp=arr[0];

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
            {
                if(arr[i]>arr[j+1])
                {
                    temp=arr[j+1];
                    arr[j+1]=arr[i];
                    arr[i]=temp;   
                }
                if(arr[i]==arr[j+1])
                {
                    arr[j+1]=arr[j+2];
                }
            }
       }

       for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
       {
           System.out.println(arr[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

But this code is throwing

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
>   at com.test.java.TestArray.main(TestArray.java:16)

Could anyone help me with this ?

Comment: issue will be here `j+2`

Comment: What is the purpose of the routine? What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to implement an array sorting?

Answer (score 0):

An attempt to index `arr[j + 1]` or `arr[j + 2]` will fail when `j` is `arr.length - 1`.

Should you run your indexes to one less than you currently do? Also, that final flourish where you index `j + 2` looks unnecessary.

As a style point, keep the scope of `temp` as tight as possible. You only need it when you swap two array elements.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to sort the array in descending order. You can try this:

```
public class TestArray
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {

        int arr[]={23,12,1,4,1,4,23,6};
        int n = arr.length;  
        int temp = 0;  
        for(int i=0; i < n; i++){  
             for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
                 if(arr[j-1] < arr[j]){  
                     //swap elements  
                     temp = arr[j-1];  
                     arr[j-1] = arr[j];  
                     arr[j] = temp;  
                 }        
             }  
        }  
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
        {
           System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can understand the code.
If you are wondering how you got exception, refer answer by [Bathsheba](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41392614/4494547)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code into

```
for(int i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++) {
    for(int j=i;j<arr.length-1;j++) {
        if(arr[i]>arr[j+1]) {
            temp=arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1]=arr[i];
            arr[i]=temp;   
        }
        if(arr[i]==arr[j+1]) {
            arr[j+1]=arr[j+2];
        }
    }
}
```

In your loop, value of j will be from 0 to 7. And you are trying to access the j+1'th position of array. So when j has value 7 you are accessing a[8] and it is not within the bounds of the array size. An array of size 8 will have index values from 0 to 7.